# Using IDs to extract ID headers and add to second column in file B

Tags: awk, python3

I have a file A that contains accession number family name and name and file B that contains ID and sequences.

I want to use the accession number in B to retrieve the family name and virus name in A and add it to the second column in B.

Example

File A

```
NC_001348 PEPS Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 3, complete genome.txt
NC_001350 PEPS Herpesviridae Saimiriine herpesvirus 2 complete genome.txt
NC_001491 PEPS Herpesviridae Equid herpesvirus 1, complete genome.txt
NC_001798 PEPS Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 2 strain HG52, complete genome.txt
NC_001806 PEPS Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 1 strain 17, complete genome.txt
NC_001826 PEPS Herpesviridae Murine herpesvirus 68 strain WUMS, complete genome.txt
NC_001844 PEPS Herpesviridae Equid herpesvirus 4, complete genome.txt
NC_001847 PEPS Herpesviridae Bovine herpesvirus 1, complete genome.txt
NC_001987 PEPS Herpesviridae Ateline herpesvirus 3 complete genome.txt
NC_002229 PEPS Herpesviridae Gallid herpesvirus 2, complete genome.txt
```

File B

```
NC_001348_71671_71760_KY215944.1    GCGCGGCTGGTGATGCAATGCGTGACCAGCTACTGGCGCAACTCGCGCTGCGCCGCCTTTGTGAACAGCTTCCCCATGGTGATGTACATC
NC_001350_89668_89757_HQ221963.1    CTTTCAGGATTTTCTGGCAGTTTTGCTGTCAAGAATGACATGATCTGGTGATGCCATATCTCAATATACAGCGCAGTGCTCACTGGTCTG
NC_001491_126502_126591_AF480884.1  AACGTGTCGGTGCGCACGGCCGTCAGGGCGAAGCCCGGGTGGATGTGGGCCTTGGTCTGCAGCACCAGCGACACCGGCGAGATCTTGTAC
NC_001798_97563_97652_AY714813.1    CGCAGGTGCCCGAAGACGTCGCAGACGGCCGCCCGCAGGGCCATGCACTGCATGGAGCCCGTGGTGCCGCCCGGCCCCCGGTCCAGGTGC
NC_001806_196955_197044_FJ483970.2  TCATCGATCTCAGTCTGTCGGCCGCTCCACGGCTCTGACTGGACTTTCCAAAGTACATACTGCAGTCAGAGCTGTCGAGCGGTTAACAGA
```

Expected Output

```
NC_001348_71671_71760_KY215944.1    Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 3, complete genome  GCGCGGCTGGTGATGCAATGCGTGACCAGCTACTGGCGCAACTCGCGCTGCGCCGCCTTTGTGAACAGCTTCCCCATGGTGATGTACATC
NC_001350_89668_89757_HQ221963.1    Herpesviridae Saimiriine herpesvirus 2 complete genome  CTTTCAGGATTTTCTGGCAGTTTTGCTGTCAAGAATGACATGATCTGGTGATGCCATATCTCAATATACAGCGCAGTGCTCACTGGTCTG
NC_001491_126502_126591_AF480884.1  Herpesviridae Equid herpesvirus 1, complete genome  AACGTGTCGGTGCGCACGGCCGTCAGGGCGAAGCCCGGGTGGATGTGGGCCTTGGTCTGCAGCACCAGCGACACCGGCGAGATCTTGTAC
NC_001798_97563_97652_AY714813.1    Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 2 strain HG52, complete genome  CGCAGGTGCCCGAAGACGTCGCAGACGGCCGCCCGCAGGGCCATGCACTGCATGGAGCCCGTGGTGCCGCCCGGCCCCCGGTCCAGGTGC
NC_001806_196955_197044_FJ483970.2  Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 1 strain 17, complete genome    TCATCGATCTCAGTCTGTCGGCCGCTCCACGGCTCTGACTGGACTTTCCAAAGTACATACTGCAGTCAGAGCTGTCGAGCGGTTAACAGA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command:

```
c=`awk '{print NR}' file2| sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`;for ((i=1;i<=$c;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{$1=$2="";print $0}' file1`; awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'NR == i{$3=$2;$2=j;print $0}' file2; done| sed "s/complete genome.txt/complete genome/g"
```

output

```
c=`awk '{print NR}' file2| sort -nr | sed -n '1p'`;for ((i=1;i<=$c;i++)); do j=`awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i{$1=$2="";print $0}' file1`; awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'NR == i{$3=$2;$2=j;print $0}' file2; done| sed "s/complete genome.txt/complete genome/g"
NC_001348_71671_71760_KY215944.1   Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 3, complete genome GCGCGGCTGGTGATGCAATGCGTGACCAGCTACTGGCGCAACTCGCGCTGCGCCGCCTTTGTGAACAGCTTCCCCATGGTGATGTACATC
NC_001350_89668_89757_HQ221963.1   Herpesviridae Saimiriine herpesvirus 2 complete genome CTTTCAGGATTTTCTGGCAGTTTTGCTGTCAAGAATGACATGATCTGGTGATGCCATATCTCAATATACAGCGCAGTGCTCACTGGTCTG
NC_001491_126502_126591_AF480884.1   Herpesviridae Equid herpesvirus 1, complete genome AACGTGTCGGTGCGCACGGCCGTCAGGGCGAAGCCCGGGTGGATGTGGGCCTTGGTCTGCAGCACCAGCGACACCGGCGAGATCTTGTAC
NC_001798_97563_97652_AY714813.1   Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 2 strain HG52, complete genome CGCAGGTGCCCGAAGACGTCGCAGACGGCCGCCCGCAGGGCCATGCACTGCATGGAGCCCGTGGTGCCGCCCGGCCCCCGGTCCAGGTGC
NC_001806_196955_197044_FJ483970.2   Herpesviridae Human herpesvirus 1 strain 17, complete genome TCATCGATCTCAGTCTGTCGGCCGCTCCACGGCTCTGACTGGACTTTCCAAAGTACATACTGCAGTCAGAGCTGTCGAGCGGTTAACAGA
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen Kumar BS, it works perfectly. I won't mind a python script too

Comment: Will post in python too KIndly upvote my answer

Comment: Hi Kumar, its like there is a little glitch.

Comment: Hi Kumar, Its like there is a little glitch. File A and B are not perfect match. The first nine characters of each line in File B are supposed to run through file A which are unique, then return the name of the accession number after PEPS and add it as second column to file B to form a new file.